# Sentiment analysis for urdu language written using latin script in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, supervised-learning

I have been using python's **TextBlob** library to get sentiment polarity for english language. 
Now  I want to get sentiment analysis(polarity) of urdu language written in latin script. 
 for example
 English sentence  : **"What is your name"**  
 
its equivalent urdu language written in latin script 
 Urdu sentence (written in latin script ) : **"Tumhara kia name hai"** 
I want suggestions, which procedure do i follow to achieve this for desired language using machine learning in both cases 
**Supervised learning**
   By using Recurrent neural networks with pre human tagged data set

"or" any **Unsupervised learning** algo ?

Comment: @lenz  i mean pronouncing or writing urdu words in using english alphabets ..

Comment: @lenz kindly check this 

https://translate.google.com.pk/?hl=en&tab=wT#ur/en/tumhara%20kia%20name%20hai

Comment: What is your actual question? A Stack-Overflow post cannot replace proper NLP training. You need to narrow down your problem much more, otherwise it's probably going to be closed as off-topic (too broad).

Comment: @lenz my question is .. what approach should i use to perform sentiment analysis on urdu text written using latin script

Comment: The problem is that this is not a programming question, but rather a research problem you can write Master's or PhD thesis about.

Comment: You can use a bag of negative and positive words of Urdu language, try using those to do sentiment analysis; (supervised learning)

Comment: @zap Okay thanks. is RNN appropriate(supervised learning algo) ? for this problem?

Comment: @DaniyalSyed this blog post by  Awais Athar might help you http://chaoticity.com/urdu-sentiment-lexicon/

Answer (score 1):

*you can use html/javascript script or python code below*

**try this script for html/javascript**(credit goes to Mr.awaisathar)

https://github.com/awaisathar/urdu-sentiment-lexicon

demo code

http://awaisathar.github.io/urdu-sentiment-lexicon/

or if you want to use in other language then use these positive and negative keywords list(below links) if this will exist/contain in you string text then you will mark it as positive otherwise negative.(if occurs is more then one then choose sentiment which has more occurrence)

Here is List of keywords

positive keyword List

https://github.com/awaisathar/urdu-sentiment-lexicon/blob/master/poisitive-words.ur.txt

negative keyword List

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awaisathar/urdu-sentiment-lexicon/master/negative-words.ur.txt

---

**for Python use this Script(Thanks to Mr.awaisathar for urdu negative and positive keywords txt file)**

https://github.com/ch-hassansaeed/urdu_sentiment_NLP_analysis

```
from urdu_sentiment_NLP_analysis_lib import get_urdu_sentiment
urdu_input_sentence="""
آپ جیسا اچھا بندہ نہیں دیکھا میں نے   
"""
urdu_sentiment_output=get_urdu_sentiment(urdu_input_sentence)
print(urdu_sentiment_output)
```

--------------------------------------- Output:postive/nautral/non-sentimental ---------------------------------------

another example:-

```
urdu_input_sentence="""
آپ بہت باتمیز انسان ہو    
"""
```

--------------------------------------- Output:negative ---------------------------------------

Comment: I have mentioned in question that i wanted to get sentiment of urdu sentence written in Latin script.

Comment: this is the logic which can even use for latain urdu.This script has two array positive and negative keywords you just need to add latin urdu words for both arrray like postiveKeywrodsArray=['acha','payra','khushi','zabardast'] ...etc
negitiveKeywrods=['nafrat','ganda','bura','batamiz'] etc...